# Is there an automatic logout in place?

Tags: support, logout

In recent weeks I found I had to login to Stack Overflow, where I normally remained logged in.

I've now found myself logged out a few times and had to log in again.  Is this a new policy, or has my cat been watching youtube videos and he logged me out first?  Or is Firefox drunk?

Comment: Any client side extensions installed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 
 
I'm not clear on what kind of client side extensions you mean. Firefox addons or is there some StackOverflow extras which I'm not aware of?

Comment: Sometimes, extensions which load their own JavaScripts can interfere with SE's namespaces. It might also be possible that some extension is deleting the browser's cache etc. Chrome calls plugins/addons as extensions, so I used that terminology, but yes; I meant addons.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks for that thought - I was going to reply that I have other sites that I remain logged into, and then it occurred to me that `Privacy Badger` is a fairly new addon and on checking it is blocking a number of things from Stack Overflow.   I expect you've solved this issue - I've disabled PB on SO and will see how it behaves.  Ta.

Comment: In fact, I also experience unexpected logouts, without any addons. I have always attributed this to my internet provider changing my IP...

Comment: @Petr, Why would changing your IP make any difference for a session cookie?

Comment: @KirkWoll, isn't pinning a session to an IP an often-used practice? That is, the cookie is still here, but the server sees that my IP has changed and no longer accepts a cookie.

Comment: @Petr, I've never heard of that.  If that were so, I would have to re-login everytime my laptop switches between my work wifi and home wifi.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'm no expert at this, but I've heard about it. A quick search founds, for example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#Verify_that_additional_information_is_consistent_throughout_session) Wikipedia paragraph. And in fact googling by "fix session ip", etc reveals that it is not uncommon. (I don't say pinning IP is good or bad.)

Comment: I noticed this problem a couple of days ago. I refreshed Stack Overflow and I was suddenly logged out of every Stack Exchange site. Managed to remember my password and get signed back in and haven't had a problem since.

Comment: @Petr , The wiki link paragraph you added doesn't refer to IP address - it mentions a timestamp in `Time-out old SIDs` and a referrer in `Destroy session if Referrer is suspicious` - just commenting that these items aren't IP based, which is what you were initially referring too.

Comment: @foxidrive, but I see there an explicit "Therefore, the security of a web site can be improved by verifying that the source IP address is consistent throughout a session."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Noticing that you're using the Privacy Badger add-on in your browser, there is [an open issue](https://github.com/EFForg/privacybadgerfirefox/issues/118) on GitHub which states:

> While Privacy Badger is enabled, website autologin is disabled. Even
>   when cookies are specifically set to remain between sessions, Privacy
>   Badger somehow destroys them upon end of session.
>
> Domains with broken autologin while Privacy Badger is enabled:
>
> - deviantart.com
> - fanfiction.net
> - pastebin.org
> - steamcommunity.com
> - steampowered.com
> - tumblr.com
>
> The list goes on...
>
> Please ensure autologin cookies and cookies with specific user-created
>   rules are safe from Privacy Badger destroying them on session end.

Comment: I use Privacy-Badger on multiple computers and I have never experienced this issue on the stack exchange network.

Comment: I've confirmed that `Privacy Badger` is the cause, and disabling it fixes the issue - thanks for your input.

Comment: I experienced the same thing using Safari on my iPad. There are definitely no client side extensions installed.

Comment: I want the server to log me out, not the client.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no automatic logout. Sounds like we've got a bug in there somewhere.

Have you been getting logged out while actively using the site?

Comment: Not while actively on the site - it's when I return after a day or three.

Comment: @foxidrive Interesting. When was the last time this happened? (Roughly - what day did you visit last and when did you come back to find yourself logged out?)

Comment: Thanks @Adam. According to Firefox history I was here on 1st Dec 8:32am and logged in 3rd Dec 6:19am - if it's significant I use this URL to return and browse the recent posts in my favourite category http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Comment: I have had this issue when I am actively using the site. Once I was doing a review, and after I was done editing a question I got the pop-up about editing anonymously and signing up. Basically, I pushed the "save edits' button and the site logged me out.

Comment: Happened to me on FF 40 once. I upgraded to FF 42, I have not experienced it since. (Mostly a problem with FF and not with SO)

Comment: The answer by hjpotter92 turned out to be spot on the money.  `Privacy Badger` wins the booby prize.  My cat is blameless!